# Can JSON.stringify output a whole number formatted as a double?

Tags: javascript, json

This is an example of what I'm doing:

```
var serialized = JSON.stringify({x: 1.0});
```

And this is the result I want:

```
{"x": 1.0}
```

But this is the result I'm getting:

```
{"x": 1}
```

I've tried using the second argument to `JSON.stringify`:

```
JSON.stringify({x: 1.0}, function (k, v) {
  if (Number.isInteger(v)) {
    return v.toFixed(1);
  }
  return v;
});
```

But that doesn't get me what I want either:

```
{"x": "1.0"}
```

Looking at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for `JSON.stringify`, I don't see an obvious way to get this to do what I want. Is there a workaround or something I'm missing?

For context, I'm taking the serialized data and passing it to an elasticsearch cluster, and I want elasticsearch to dynamically create a mapping for the `x` field (in the example). However, if the first number that elasticsearch sees is `1` and not `1.0`, it will create a long mapping instead of a double mapping, and future double `x` values (e.g. `1.5`) would cause elasticsearch parsing to fail.

Comment: Short answer, no. You cannot turn `1` into `1.0` and keep it as a number. `1.0` is `1` - so unless it's a string, it will always be converted to the smallest number. If it's only the first instance that sets up your elastic search - push a dummy object with `x: 1.1` and it'll grab that

Comment: @tymeJV if I knew in advance what all the property names were going to be (e.g. `x`, `y`, `z`, etc.), then I could just create a mapping with the correct types, but I do not, since the documents are log messages.

The fact is, if I wrote my own `stringify` function, I could definitely get what I want, but I'm wondering if there's a way to use `JSON.stringify` to get what I want so I don't have to roll my own.

Comment: This seems to be a view-specific requirement so consider using something equivalent of Pipes in Angular 2 / Filters in AngularJS.

Comment: simplest (nasty) hack would be to `.replace()` the json, altering raw ints: `JSON.stringify({x: 1.0}).replace(/:(\d{1})([,}])/g,":$1.0$2")`

Answer (score 3):

Taking the idea of a using the replacer function of JSON.stringify and String#replace and a small addition to the number for finding the integer to replace.

It could look like this:

```js
var s = JSON.stringify({ x: 1.0 }, function (k, v) {
        if (Number.isInteger(v)) {
            return v + 1e-10;
        }
        return v;
    }).replace(/\.0000000001/, '.0');

console.log(s);
```

Comment: It's ugly, hacky, clever, and probably a pretty reasonable workaround considering.

Comment: This is by far the best solution I found for this problem, however I found that instead of `0.0` it writes `1e-10`, so I've added second replace for that string. And you need to add `g` - global flag for replace.

Comment: @Pawel then try a greater number, like '1e-9'

Answer (score 0):

`1.0` and `1` are equivalent in javascript, since there's no such thing as int/double/long in the language. Instead, you will need to add type data to make it completely clear what type you're expecting the result to be.

```
{"x": {"type": "double", "value": 1}}
```

Comment: This doesn't really help me. I'm aware that `1.0` and `1` are equivalent in JavaScript. This isn't a question about JavaScript as much as it is about `JSON.stringify` and whether I can manipulate it to do what I want (e.g. return a string without double quotes around a `1.0`).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? They are semantically identical to any JSON processor. There is no reason to want `1.0` instead of `1`.

Comment: @StevenOxley so you can do what? Call `JSON.parse` on it? That would change your `1.0` into a `1`. Now, let's say you also rig `JSON.parse` to parse it into `1.0`. Wait, `1.0` is equivalent to `1`. There's no way out of this. (this is true for any JSON parser. I used JSON.parse for simplicity but the same is true for a parser in Java, for example)

Comment: @torazaburo it is not identical to any JSON processor. I explained why I wanted to do this in the question (elasticsearch handles them differently, see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/dynamic-field-mapping.html#numeric-detection).

@tcooc I am not using `JSON.parse`, and not all JSON parsers work as you describe (elasticsearch's doesn't - see link above).

Comment: Oh wait - I just realized that elasticsearch has support for parsing numbers from strings. That's probably all I need. Also, judging by the answers/comments, it looks like the answer to my question is "No, it's not possible and there isn't an easy workaround."