# Force decimal value, even on integers, in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to take a user-input value and force it to 6 decimal places, even if the value is an integer. For example, the user types in 12, I need to convert that to `12.000000`, **as a number**. This is not for display purposes - the system on the other end of my app *requires* decimal values, and there's nothing I can do about that.

As I've read elsewhere, numbers in Javascript are all 64-bit floating point numbers, so it doesn't seem like this should be so difficult.

Alas, `toFixed` is not an option here because that gives me a string value `'12.000000'`. Every other trick I've tried just yields the integer `12` with no decimal zeroes (e.g. wrapping `toFixed` with `Number`, dividing the string value by 1, and other such silliness).

Is it possible to represent an integer as a float in Javascript, without ending up with a string value?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for all the comments and answers. Unfortunately for me, @Enzey's comment actually answers my core question when he said that forcing precision can only be done with a string. If he submits that as an answer I'll accept it. I kept the details of my implementation purposefully vague because I didn't want to get into why I wanted to do what I'm doing, I just wanted to know if it was possible. But I guess I just ended up confusing people. Sorry about that.

Comment: do you need it for a json string?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "the other end of my app requires decimal values" what is that? How are you sending the number to that "other end" of the system? Is the number going into JSON and sent across the wire? Looking at other languages like Java or C# the numbers `12.0` and `12.000` are identical. Not sure how you could force exactly 6 digits of precision...

Comment: Actually... if you are dealing with user inputted values, are you just missing a `.parseFloat()` on the input string? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat Maybe you are just unintentionally sending it to the backend as a string?

Comment: As a number you cannot force the precision, that can only be done as a string.

Comment: what happens if it has 7 decimal places?  Does your "other end" chop it off at 6?  If so, just add 0.0000001 to all your integers.

Comment: @andi the odd moment when the number is 0.9999999

Comment: @ASDFGerte You can test for the original number's precision in advance, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately what you seek is not possible via Javascript. @1sloc states this in the most concise way. If this is a hard and fast requirement your only option seems to be to build the JSON as a string by hand ... god help you.

Comment: it look like a zombie [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271759/can-json-stringify-output-a-whole-number-formatted-as-a-double)

Comment: `the system on the other end of my app requires decimal values` too bad because it's literally impossible to do it. The question is _how_ are you handing off the data? Because it's impossible to give a JS number to a completely unrelated system. Heck, you can't hand over any value _but_ text from JS to elsewhere. At best you can do JSON but that _is_ text. Sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem here - convert numeric values as strings to keep the precision and figure out why that "doesn't work" or even _if_.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, there is no such thing as `float` or `int` in JavaScript. You only have `Number`, which does not have the slightest clue about a difference between `12` and `12.000000`.

Comment: `a difference between 12 and 12.000000` yeah, in most other languages one will be an int, the other a float (of some description). Yet, in fairness, even then, floats won't differentiate between `12.0` and `12.000000`. I don't actually know of any language takes into account decimal zeroes when these values are stored as primitive numeric values. Custom objects or strings will be able to represent them, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending it as a stringified JSON, you can use `.toFixed` on the number, and then strip the " signs from the numbers in the stringified JSON:

```js
var result = JSON.stringify({
    number: (12).toFixed(6)
  })
  .replace(/"[\d]+\.\d{6}"/g, function(v) {
    return v.replace(/"/g, '');
  });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This frightens me greatly.
This works great until it hits something that matches the expression but should actually be a string. Such as any manually user input value.

Comment: However, since you know that the number of decimals is 6, and it's a number in a string format, you can tailor your regex specifically for this case. Besides, I don't think that he has another option except for the "build the JSON as a string by hand ... god help you" one :)

Comment: I didn't say you were wrong, just the idea that this is needed is frightening. The JSON needs to be mucked with at some level due to the backend parsing requirements. Which is really where the issue should be handled.

Comment: I agree with you. This is hackish, and for a weird problem.

Comment: @OriDrori I doubt that would help. Unless the JSON parser on the other end is rather custom, I doubt it'll preserve the zeroes. Heck, they might even be truncated on transmission, depending on how it's done.